# Converting an array of letter to an array of numbers

Tags: c, arrays

I have a text file in D drive named "data.txt". It has several columns and rows like:

```
A B A B V B
B V A B A A
B B A A B A
```

I want to read the "program.txt" file and then convert it to numbers say A=1, B=2, V=3 and then write it so that it will be a array of number.  But I'm not sure where to begin. Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
#include <stdio.h>

 int main() {
    int n,k;
    char C;
    FILE *fptr;
    fptr=fopen("D:\\program.txt","r+");
    printf("Enter n: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    if (n == C){
        fprintf(fptr,"%d",3);
    }
    fclose(fptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please show what you've tried so far.

Comment: You're going to get snarky responses like: "Read the data, convert it, then write it", until you show us what you've done.  By doing so, you'll let us know how best to help you understand your issue.  What you've done so far is ask us to understand your issue for you.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp where did that code example come from?

Comment: Yeah, I'm thinking that's not the right code. Got it from his comment.

Comment: Hahah oh I didn't even see it there.  My brain just stopped when the comment turned into code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char line_buff[16];
    FILE *fptr;
    fpos_t pos;
    fptr=fopen("D:\\program.txt","r+");
    fgetpos(fptr, &pos);
    while(fgets(line_buff, sizeof(line_buff), fptr)){//read one line
        char *p = line_buff;
        while(*p){//convert
            if(*p == 'A')
                *p++ = '1';
            else if(*p == 'B')
                *p++ = '2';
            else if(*p == 'V')
                *p++ = '3';
            else
                ++p;
        }
        fsetpos(fptr, &pos);
        fprintf(fptr, "%s", line_buff);//rewrite
        fflush(fptr);
        fgetpos(fptr, &pos);//memo position
    }
    fclose(fptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From your question, it looks like you want to assign a new number to each character as you encounter it.  So you need to keep track of what you've seen and what number was assigned, as well as the current number.

You can do this with an array:

```
int values[256] = {0};
int next_value = 1;
```

When you read a character, you can check if you've already seen it.  You may also want to check that it's in the right range.  If you haven't seen it, assign a number.  Otherwise use the number that was originally assigned:

```
if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') {
    if (!values[c]) values[c] = next_value++;
    printf ("%d", values[c]);
}
```

Then it's just a matter of reading the file.  There are many ways to do this, but I think the simplest in this case is to read each character from the file in a loop and output them after translating the ones you're interested in:

```
int c;
while (EOF != (c = getc(fp))) {
    if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') {
        if (!values[c]) values[c] = next_value++;
        printf ("%d", values[c]);
    } else { 
        putchar(c);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can see the program here: http://ideone.com/HPZqo0 - it reads from `stdin` instead of file, but you get the idea.